# How to clip this textbutton above circle avatar in stack?

Tags: flutter

[image]

Sorry for the simple question, I did a lot of googling still unable to find proper solution.
Is there any way other than the custom clipper?

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  children: [
    CircleAvatar(
      radius: 100,
      foregroundImage:
          _pickedImage == null ? null : FileImage(_pickedImage!),
      child: const Icon(
        Icons.person_outlined,
        size: 40,
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
      width: 200,
      height: 50,
      child: TextButton.icon(
        onPressed: _pickImage,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.image),
        label: const Text(
          "Upload Image",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `Stack` widget with `ClipRRect` widget and specify the `borderRadius` property, check example below:

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        ...
      ]
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked by wrapping it in SizedBox, and mistakenly I was using Column cross axis alignment stretched as a parent widget, which was causing error.